# select one column of GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I have a GridView with two columns, that an ArrayList fill out the GridView.
My CustomAdapter handle data between GridView and ArrayList.
The GridView choiceMode is single in my GridView xml file,and i can select from the left column and right column both.
now i want to select just from the left column and not the right.

here is my GridView design XML :

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:background="#E6B800"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
```

and here is my CustomAdapter Class :

```
 public class CustomAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context contex;
    int id;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;



    public CustomAdapter(Context contex, int layoutId, ArrayList<String> arrayList)
    {
        super(contex, id, arrayList);
        this.contex = contex;
        this.layoutId = id;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

}
```

and here is my usage of CustomAdapter in another Class :

```
customAdapter =  new CustomAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, myList);
```

and here how i fill out the ArrayList :

```
   myList.add(driverName);
   myList.add(plateNumber);
   customAdapter.getItemViewType(R.id.gridView);
   myAdapter.isEnabled(myAdapter.getPosition(plateNumber));
   myGridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

driverName and plateNumber are String that added to ListView

And after data entered into my List( after while loop ) i added this code to prevent select both column, but it doesnt work  :

```
customAdapter.areAllItemsEnabled();
customAdapter.isEnabled(customAdapter.getPosition(plateNumber));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, i changed the solution.
I used two listView instead of one GridView with two rows.
and sync their movement.
if you google, you will find out how to sync two ListView movement.